# Is there a locate-library equivalent for Common Lisp files?

Tags: common-lisp

When editing Common Lisp code, is there an Emacs command that behaves like `locate-library` that would take a name and attempt to find the location for a Common Lisp file with that name?

Looking at Slime and SLY manuals I did not find that feature.  Does it exists?

I know I can find the location of a specific function when using Slime or SLY.  But let's say I just downloaded a library, possibly with Quicklisp, and I'd like to look at its code, I'd use that command to quickly visit or edit these files.